# Body fields gone on all pages after upgrade to Organic Groups 7.x-2.3

Tags: nodes, entities, organic-groups, wysiwyg

I'm having a big issue where the body content from all of the pages of my site -- even those that have nothing to do with Organic Groups -- has vanished since I upgraded to OG 7.x-2.3. I've searched dozens of posts in different forums and can't find an answer.

I originally thought the problem was limited to OG because the text that users had entered into each group's posts disappeared after the upgrade. But then I looked at other pages of my site, and wherever the body field appeared in other nodes (both the summary text of teasers and expanded full content), the text had also disappeared. Only the body text is affected; users can see the title, "submitted by" line, and "read more" link in the teasers, and they can see the title and "submitted by" line in the full content node, just not any body text.

The weird thing, though, is that if a user clicks on the "edit" tab, they can see what they wrote; it's only when they hit "save" that it disappears.  I've made sure that the body content in the CCK fields isn't hidden; I've tried changing the format to "plain text" and other formats; and I've tried disabling the OG Field Access module and the OG Context module, clearing the cache, and then re-enabling them (something a lot of people suggest doing), but nothing seems to work. I've even tried disabling the WYSISYG-related modules to see if they were the culprit, but it didn't do the trick.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be? I've been tearing my hair out over this for a long time and can't fiture it out.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. In addition to the other things I tried above, I also tried uninstalling Display Suite and clearing the cache, in addition to adding the argument "from context" -> "Content ID" in Views (I'm using a panel override to display the OG content) but still nothing is working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the "Rebuild permissions" at Admin > Reports > Status > Node Access Permissions?

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for your response. Yes, I already tried rebuilding the permissions to no avail. I've given everyone permission to view the body text of every node, and yet the body text is missing from several different pages. Not sure what's the matter here. So frustrating.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I've been messing around in the database and don't see anything out of sort. I wonder if some module is interfering with the visibility of the body fields? Is it enough to disable modules like Display Suite, for instance, or do I need to totally delete them from the database? I'm running on empty here and need some help or else my site won't be able to launch. Please help!